# json object creation in servlet gives error

Tags: java, json, servlets

after i upload this servlet to my server it gives error no page can be render to browser response was same error given below. If i comment json objetc part in this servlet. server response work well.

The browser gives error.

### ERROR

```
 The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. 
 The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.
```

servlet:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONException;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class FBOAuth extends HttpServlet {

public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    String code = request.getParameter("code");
    if (code == null || code.equals("")) {
    }

    String token = null;
    try {
        String g = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=187359628094571&redirect_uri=" + URLEncoder.encode("http://proshelf-sivagnanam.rhcloud.com/fb.do", "UTF-8") + "&client_secret=3bada871309843a626e9ca4c1cd76fc8&code=" + code;
        URL u = new URL(g);
        URLConnection c = u.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            b.append(inputLine + "\n");
        in.close();
token = b.toString();
        if (token.startsWith("{"))
            throw new Exception("error on requesting token: " + token + " with code: " + code);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            // an error occurred, handle this
    }

    String graph = null;
    try {
        String g = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?" + token;
        URL u = new URL(g);
        URLConnection c = u.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            b.append(inputLine + "\n");
        in.close();
        graph = b.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
            // an error occurred, handle this
    }

    String facebookId = null;
    String firstName = null;
    String middleNames = null;
    String lastName = null;
    String email = null;
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(graph);
        facebookId = json.getString("id");
        firstName = json.getString("first_name");
        if (json.has("middle_name"))
           middleNames = json.getString("middle_name");
        else
            middleNames = null;
        if (middleNames != null && middleNames.equals(""))
            middleNames = null;
        lastName = json.getString("last_name");
        email = json.getString("email");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
}
}
```

Comment: Where in your code does this error occur?

Comment: error is actually when i try to access any page in my application it give the error i mention above. no content is rendered to browser only error which i mentioned.

Comment: On Chrome right click the browser, click Inspect Element, then click Network. Refresh the page and click the entry to which the browser requests to your servlet. Show the requests and response headers to us.

Comment: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: proshelf-sivagnanam.rhcloud.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/30.0.1599.114 Chrome/30.0.1599.114 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Response Headersview parsed
response: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 08 Apr 2014 16:31:01 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain

Comment: Where in your code do you print out your JSON string? I cannot see any calls instances of PrintWriter.out().

Comment: I first creating a string look like json String graph;. then i give the string as input to JSONObject json = new JSONObject(graph); i did not print any json string. when i add the above statement i could not access any file in my server."NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://proshelf-sivagnanam.rhcloud.com/"
proshe...oud.com
The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. error returned.

Comment: The best thing you can do to troubleshoot this problem is to include a n `e.printStackTrace()` inside your **catch** blocks.